# HTTP request restarts Internet connection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Recently I started to develop web API for my windows phone 8 app and when I try to connect it to my app (via WebClient, HttpRequest and HttpClient) it ends the same way, just disconnects my Internet connection without any information. Site I am trying to reach is `gtlol.necroworks.net/free`. Any one else came across similar situation and/or found any answer?

**More description:**

Examples of HttpClient and WebClient requests:

```
//HttpClient example
using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
{
   hc.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://gtlol.necroworks.net/");

   HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.GetAsync("free");
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
       var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       MessageBox.Show(res);
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Not working - no internet connection");
   }
}

//WebClient example
WebClient freeRotationWebClient = new WebClient();
freeRotationWebClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_GetRotation);
freeRotationWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://gtlol.necroworks.net/free"));

private void webClient_GetRotation(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((string)e.Result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not working");
    }
}
```

Both of em should return this result:

```
[{"_id":"53d264aa6e65634e49000000","champId":53},{"_id":"53d264ab6e65634e49010000","champId":36},{"_id":"53d264ab6e65634e49020000","champId":79},{"_id":"53d264ab6e65634e49030000","champId":96},{"_id":"53d264ab6e65634e49040000","champId":75},{"_id":"53d264ab6e65634e49050000","champId":72},{"_id":"53d264ac6e65634e49060000","champId":48},{"_id":"53d264ac6e65634e49070000","champId":6},{"_id":"53d264ac6e65634e49080000","champId":101},{"_id":"53d264ac6e65634e49090000","champId":115}]
```

But when any request tries to get this result it just ends in Internet connection reset, without any message or any warning or any exception. Only thing I could get from debugger was info that request got status code 404.

Any other web API service I use works normally.

One thing I noticed are headers I get from my api are:

```
Accept-Ranges →bytes
Age →0
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →482
Content-Type →application/json;charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 30 Jul 2014 18:44:45 GMT
Server →nginx
Via →1.1 varnish
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Varnish →584616320
```

Where api I want to cache is using:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →161
Content-Type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date →Wed, 30 Jul 2014 18:45:13 GMT
Server →Jetty(9.1.1.v20140108)
Vary →Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
X-NewRelic-App-Data →#string of chars here
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a response from a public HTTP cache, instead of from your origin server.  It is possible that the cache (Varnish) has stored a copy of a previous 404 response and is now happily serving that in response to your request and will continue until the response becomes stale.  How long that is depends what max-age/expires is set by the server.

You could try adding a cache-control header to your request that indicates you don't want to get a cached response.  Try doing,

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage() {
                             RequestUri = new Uri("free",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                          }; 
request.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeader() {NoCache=true};
HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.SendAsync(request);
```

Be warned that I wrote this without intellisense, nor a compiler, so expect typos!